# Initialize SQL on app start in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a java class called `getdata` which contains some SQL code which shows on another java class as a `listview`, my problem is every time i try to view the data it freezes up for a little while and then displays the data because i am getting my data from a cloud database. Is there anyway to initialize this SQL code to run when i start my application where the user is busy logging in and keeps the array on ram so that the app does not lag when i try to view my products

Here is my `getdata.java`:

```
public class GetData {
Connection connect;
String ConnectionResult = "";
Boolean isSuccess = false;




public List<Map<String,String>> doInBackground() {

    List<Map<String, String>> data = null;
    data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    try
    {
        ConnectionHelper conStr=new ConnectionHelper();
        connect =conStr.connectionclass();        // Connect to database
        if (connect == null)
        {
            ConnectionResult = "Check Your Internet Access!";
        }
        else
        {
            // Change below query according to your own database.
            String query = "select * from cc_rail";
            Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()){
                Map<String,String> datanum=new HashMap<String,String>();
                datanum.put("NAME",rs.getString("RAIL_NAME"));

                datanum.put("PRICE",rs.getString("RAIL_UNIT_PRICE"));

                datanum.put("RANGE",rs.getString("RAIL_RANGE"));

                datanum.put("SUPPLIER",rs.getString("RAIL_SUPPLIER"));

                datanum.put("SIZE",rs.getString("RAIL_SIZE"));
                data.add(datanum);
            }


            ConnectionResult = " successful";
            isSuccess=true;
            connect.close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        isSuccess = false;
        ConnectionResult = ex.getMessage();
    }

    return data;
}
```

and here is my `.java` file where i view the data and the lag happens:

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_valance, container, false);

    list = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.raill);
    add = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.PB_Getting);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),Add_valance.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


          List<Map<String,String>> MyData = null;
            GetValence mydata =new GetValence();
            MyData= mydata.doInBackground();
            String[] fromwhere = { "NAME","PRICE","SIZE" ,"RANGE","SUPPLIER"};

            int[] viewswhere = {R.id.Name_txtView , R.id.price_txtView,R.id.size_txtView};

            ADAhere = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), MyData,R.layout.list_valence, fromwhere, viewswhere);

            list.setAdapter(ADAhere);
```

Comment: You may be experiencing lag if you are attempting to get data from a database on the main `thread`. I would put that in another thread (ie `AsyncTask`) if you have not already. As for your `array`, you can call the function to download the data from the database in your `onCreate` for your main class. Then, either pass the array as an `extra` in the `intent` or store the array in another class as a `static` variable. Let me know if this helps or if you have any questions. Good luck.

Comment: @Jacob in my `getdata` file when i extend it to `AsyncTask` how do use with one one abstract method because i only have my `doinbackground` in the `getdata` file

Comment: Your class that extends `AsyncTask` should look something like this: https://ibb.co/kF9cid. The `onPostExecute` method is where you want to save your array data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was talking about in the comments.

`GetData.java`:

```
public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Map<String, String>> {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> doInBackground(String... params) {
        //do your thing here
        return resultMap;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Map<String, String> result) {
        StorageClass.setArrayData(result);
    }
}
```

`StorageClass.java`:

```
public class StorageClass {
    private static Map<String,String> arrayData = new HashMap<>();

    public static void setArrayData(Map<String,String> results){
        arrayData = results;
    }

    public static Map<String, String> getArrayData(){
        return arrayData;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have the code `List<Map<String, String>> data = null;` which is different to map so when i return data it is incompatible, i assume `return resultmap` is same to my codes `return data`? how would i fix the List

Comment: If you want the `AsyncTask` to return `List<Map<String, String>>`, simply change all instances of `Map<String, String>` in my example to `List<Map<String, String>>`.